# How can I export data view?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sequelpro

I have a view in phpmyadmin and I would like to download the table that the view creates in a SQL file. (click on view->export data->ok)

But when I import the downloaded SQL file in Sequel Pro I get the error:

```
[ERROR in query 7] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has() on n' at line 4
```

So that basically means there is no data in the exported file. How can I download the data resulting from a View in phpmyadmin correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A view don't contain data so when you download/export the view instead of data you probably download/export the related code .. you want to download the data  .. you should create a temporary table  as select  from the view

```
create my_temp_table 
select * from my_view
```

then download/export the my_temp_table